# global PHP variable returning NULL within function inside same file

Tags: php, json

So I've set a local variable $polls to have contain a JSON array, but a function within the same file will return NULL as the value of $poll when I do a var_dump of the variable from within a function.

```
$polls = json_decode(file_get_contents($lib_path . '/polls.json'), true);
var_dump($polls); //this returns the information within $polls correctly

function getPoll() {
    var_dump($polls); //this returns NULL
}
```

I've tried (in vain) to use 'global', but shouldn't $polls easily be within scope? I've checked that $polls has not been defined anywhere else within the codebase that I'm working with.

Comment: Variable scope, the function has no idea what the value of $polls is (or that a variable called $polls even exists) outside itself

Comment: See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 5):

Variables in the global namespace are not available inside of functions unless you explicitly make them so. There are three ways to do this:

**Pass them as a parameter** (recommended)

```
function getPoll($polls){
    var_dump($polls);
}
```

**Use the `global` keyword** (strongly not recommended)

```
function getPoll(){
    global $polls
    var_dump($polls);
}
```

**Use the `$GLOBALS` superglobal** (strongly not recommended)

```
function getPoll(){
    $polls = $GLOBALS['polls'];
    var_dump($polls);
}
```

Comment: I feel like there may be a larger problem here. Even if I use the two strongly not recommended `global $polls;` and `$polls = $GLOBALS['polls'];`, it still won't `var_dump[$polls]` correctly. Any insight into why that may be?

Comment: Did you try the first option?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$polls = json_decode(file_get_contents($lib_path . '/polls.json'), true);
var_dump($polls); //this returns the information within $polls correctly

function getPoll($p) {
var_dump($p); //this returns NULL
}
//call class
getPoll($poll);
```

I see you not passing anything through the parameters

Answer (score 0):

pass it in as a parameter:

```
 function getPoll($polls) {
   var_dump($polls); 
 }

 getPoll($polls);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `global` declaration to access a global variable from inside a function:

```
function getPoll() {
    global $polls;
    var_dump($polls); //this returns NULL
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/xm9Eru)

Comment: Please don't keep recommending `global` as the universal panacea to all scope problems

Comment: I'm not recommending it, I'm answering the question about how to do what he wants to do.

Comment: Funny enough, `global` isn't even working for me to begin with, so that solution is out.

Comment: There's no reason `global` shouldn't work like this. There must be something you're not explaining correctly in the question.

Comment: No, I'm here (many years later) for the same reason. There must be some reason `global` doesn't work, because, it doesn't, ergo there's a reason. It would be nice to know what that reason is, for sure.

Comment: @JohnSmith Ask a new question with a [mre] that demonstrates the problem. I'm just guessing, but maybe it has to do with namespaces.